# get configuration scope selector for custom module

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore

I'm working on a module where I need to save the records based on the scope of *website* and *store*. For that I need to have the **select** box as its in the **system->configuration**.

[image: website configuration scope - magento]

`How can I get that select box in my form` and save the *website/store* value in database so that it can be displayed in the specific *store/website*? Any suggestions on it?

Now I'm trying it breaking into two fields -> **website** and **store**. Now, how can I change the options in store based on the **website** selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I'd written my own code for this.

```
    $scope = array('default' => 'default');
    foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
        $scope['website_' . $website->getCode()] = $website->getName();
        foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
            $stores = array();
            foreach ($group->getStores() as $store) {
                $stores[] = array(
                    'label' => $store->getName(),
                    'value' => 'store_' . $store->getCode()
                );
            }
            $scope[] = array(
                'label' => $website->getName(),
                'value' => $stores
            );
        }
    }
    $fieldset->addField('website', 'select', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('designer')->__('Website'),
        'name' => 'website',
        'values' => $scope
    ));
```

Thanks to this [post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/411310/#t445232) by [Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius)